# How to Fit an Exponential Model Where the Rate Parameter Depends on Explanatory Variable

Tags: regression, generalized-linear-model, predictive-models, modeling, model

I have some waiting times $y_i$ and some explanatory variables $x_i$. I am trying to create a model where each $y_i$ follows an exponential distribution with rate parameter dependent on $x_i$. What is the usual way to do this? Of course the rate parameters must be constrained greater than $0$. I have thought of fitting $y_i \sim \text{exp}(e^{\beta_0 + \beta_1 x_i})$ but am not sure if there is a better alternative?

Thanks,

Jack

Answer (score 0):

This question is answered here
https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2003-June/034852.html.

I quote 
"
The Gamma family is parametrized in `glm()` by two parameters: 
mean and dispersion; the "dispersion" regulates the shape.

So must fit a GLM with the Gamma family, and then produce a `summary`
with dispersion parameter set equal to 1, since this value 
corresponds to the exponential distribution in the Gamma family.

In practice:

`fit <- glm(formula =...,  family = Gamma)
summary(fit,dispersion=1)`